# How to transform http.get() response so that component is able to directly consume the result

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to transform the result of a data fetch, so that it is ready to be  consumed by a component.

- The response is returned as an object.
- I need need to project the property `keywords` of the object, it contains an array of objects:

```
interface GetKeywordsResponse {
   business : BusinessObj, 
   keywords : Array<KeywordObj>
}
```

- For each object in the array, I want to project the property `keyword`

```
interface KeywordObj {
 id: number,
 keyword: string
 }
```

Giving me an array of strings:
`//['foo', 'bar']`

I understand that I need to `pipe()` and `map()` to achieve this. But my solution is generating type errors.

Service method:

```
public getKeywords(): Observable<Array<string>>  {
    return this.http.get<Observable<GetKeywordsResponse>>(...url).pipe(
      map((res: GetKeywordsResponse): Array<KeywordObj> => res.keywords),
      map((res: KeywordObj): Array<string> => res.keyword )
  }
```

I expect the method to work without any problems. However I encounter two errors:

```
1. Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<GetKeywordsResponse, KeywordObj[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Observable<GetKeywordsResponse>, KeywordObj[]>'.
 Type 'GetKeywordsResponse' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<GetKeywordsResponse>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.

2. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
```

How can I fix getKeywords()?

Comment: ensure that you're importing `map` from `rxjs/operators`, not from `rxjs`. Also, currently you get an `Observable<string>`, not `Observable<Array<string>>` as `keyword` is a single string. Try adding `toArray()` operator after the maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public getKeywords(): Observable<string[]>  {
   return this.http.get(`${this.uri}/businesses/${this.businessId}/keywords`).pipe(
     map((res: GetKeywordsResponse): Array<KeywordObj> => res.keywords),
     map((arr: Array<KeywordObj>): string[] => arr.map((obj: KeywordObj): string => obj.keyword)))
 }
```

- The input for 2nd map was returning an array of objects. I made the error of thinking that it was an item in the array of objects.